# Проблема с работой с mysql в django test

Tags: python, mysql, django, база-данных

Мигрировал с sqlite3 -> mysql, в связи с чем заказщик купил на хостинге доступ к БД mysql. Провел миграции все ок. Запустил сайт - все ок. Выполнял операции с сайтом вручную (создавал различные сущности, изменял их и просматривал) - все ок, то есть база данных работает корректно. Однако когда пытаюсь запустить тесты:

```
alex@alex-YOGA11S:~/PycharmProjects/WebGalaxyIdent$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1045, "Access denied for user 'FrolovPV'@'%' (using password: YES)")
```

Мне рекомендовали выдать моему пользователю права на создание БД, но я не могу это сделать так как у меня нет доступа напрямую к серверу, а бд крутится на хостинге.

Так же это довольно глупо: миграции смогли создать базы данных, через PHPMyAdmin доступ работает, базы вручную создаются, а вот тестом не хватает доступа.

Что мне может помочь?

Comment: Возможно он непрвильно подставляет адрес хоста, вообще не понятно в чем дело.

Comment: А зачем вы запускаете тесты на хостинге? Обычно тесты запускают в среде для разработки

Comment: Разумеется я их запускаю в среде разработке у меня на локальном пк, но подключаюсь к бд mysql на хостинге, так как она очень большая и работать локально не получается.

Comment: А зачем вам для тестов нужна большая бд на хостинге? Обычно для тестов создают новую пустую бд

Comment: Дело в том что для работы сайта нужно очень много сущностей (галактик) и тесты проверяют их классификацию. Если предположить что та база данных га сервере пустая, то тесты не запускаются даже с ней

Comment: То есть вы проверяете на самом деле не работу движка сайта, а целостность базы данных? Тогда, вероятно, это должны быть вообще не тесты, а какая-нибудь management-команда, которая запускается всё-таки прямо на хостинге

Comment: Окей, эта база данных используется ТОЛЬКО для разработки, так что тесты мы должны тоже запускать на ней. Я проверяю именно функциональность сайта, и поэтому реализую это через тесты. Но python3 manage.py test не хочет работать с этой БД. (До этого там использовалась SQLite3 и все работало отлично)

Comment: Проблема была в том, что Djnango пытался создать еще одну БД для тестов (а не таблицу, как на sqllite), к чему у него не было доступа